# Polka dot beamsplitter. Is it good for gaussian beams

Tags: optics, reflection, polarization

I am doing pump probe and I am looking for beam-splitter which will not affect beam polarization too much, as I intend to measure polarization dependencies. I have heard of polka-dot beam-splitters before but don't know anybody who would have ever used them.

So I wonder if anyone knows a) What is the ellipticity and rotation for such BS?
b) How strongly the beam quality is affected?

Maybe someone is aware of good alternative.

Comment: Would a thin-film metallized splitter serve? You may lose some intensity uniformity but they're pretty good at not affecting polarization, either in splitting ratio or  s vs p rotation.

Comment: Do you have any particular in mind? I've checked Thorlabs and Newport and did not find thin-film metallized splitters there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I didn't know these beam splitters. However they do not look right if you want to preserve the (I assume arbitrary) polarization state of the input beam in the 2 outputs.
For example in Thorlabs they do not even specify the s and p reflectivity: usually it is a bad sign. They look designed to have constant transmission and reflection on a large spectrum (good for pulses), but probably bad polarization proprieties (but I can be wrong).

The best ones I found and use so far are [these](http://www.newport.com/Laser-Line-Non-Polarizing-Cube-Beamsplitters/141121/1033/info.aspx) (3% s-p, but for narrow band). Otherwise [these](http://www.newport.com/Broadband-Non-Polarizing-Cube-Beamsplitters/141119/1033/info.aspx) (10% s-p, large band).

Comment: But why would they screw polarization? I would expect them to behave similarly to metallic mirrors which are generally not bad.

Answer (score 1):

The polka dot beam-splitter works just like a mirror, but patterned in a 100um grid. The 100um grid will create a coarse diffraction pattern, and if that bothers you then you could instead use a beam pickoff, like these: [D pickoff](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2632)). Barring an unusual wavelength of light, you should be able to preserve (linear) polarization to a fraction of a percent (as suggested by Ivan Madan).

However, note that even metal mirrors cause circularly polarized light to rotate!

Metal "beam-splitters" aren't perfect for all applications (or even all pump-probe experiments). As SCRX2 has pointed out, non-polarizing cubes seem to have the best polarization performance of typical non-polarizing beamsplitters. But, if you have power to spare, you could do better by combining polarizing beam-splitters with a couple of half-waveplates and linear polarizers.

All that said I think ellipsometery setups usually use metal mirrors (when they need them).